# Prevent connection string pollution attacks in Python, if needed

Tags: python, security, sqlalchemy, pymongo, sql-injection

I want to return results of a predefined query when passed a user's userid and password for the database.

The query is constant, so not the basic SQL injection scenario.

However, does allowing a user to specify username and password that will be `.format()`-ted into the connection string pose any vulnerability?

(I found [a source](https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/detail?id=desc.dataflow.dotnet.connection_string_parameter_pollution#Python) suggesting it does -- mostly I'm interested in `sqlalchemy.create_engine` and `pymongo.MongoClient` but would be interested in any common data stores and python modules.)

How should I modify the below example to sanitize the inputs, if needed?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine # requires module: psycopg2
import urllib.parse
import pandas as pd
import getpass

CONSTANT_QUERY_STRING = "SELECT * FROM table1;"
DB_URI = 'postgresql://{db_user}:{db_password}@postgres.acme.com:5432/acme_db'

class DbConnector:
  def __init__(self, db_uri, db_user, db_password):
    self.uri = db_uri.format(db_user=db_user, db_password=urllib.parse.quote_plus(db_password))

  def get_data(self, query):
      engine = create_engine(self.uri)
      df = pd.read_sql_query(query, con=engine)
      engine.dispose()
      return df

if __name__ == "__main__":
    userid = input('User: ')
    password = getpass.getpass('Password for {}:'.format(userid))
    df = DbConnector(DB_URI,userid,password).get_data(CONSTANT_QUERY_STRING)
    if df:
        print("Here's your data!")
        print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any injection of any kind - it depends in the special characters an attacker is able to inject and the accepted URI format.
Let's say I inject the following values:

Username: user

Password: 
password@malicious.server.com:5432/acme_db?

or

password@malicious.server.com:5432/acme_db#

What would be the outcome?

postgresql://user:password@malicious.server.com:5432/acme_db?@postgres.acme.com:5432/acme_db

postgresql://user:password@malicious.server.com:5432/acme_db#@postgres.acme.com:5432/acme_db

Your application would connect to a different DB and the behavior might be modified completely. I don't know if these URI formats would be accepted or not, but the question is: **why take the chance?**

You know what the valid username and password structure is, just validate it and encode special characters that you allow (if you want to allow any character in passwords). Probably URI encoding will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

For SQLAlchemy, you can automatically URL-encode special characters by passing a [URL](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.URL) instance instead of using a formatted (or otherwise composed) string. This will neutralise* the type of attacks described in [Gil Cohen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2464918/gil-cohen)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61441053/5320906). URL instances should be created using the [URL.create](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create) constructor.

```py
from sqlalchemy import URL

drivername = 'postgresql'
user = 'alice'
password = 'password@bad.example.com:5432/secretdb?'
host = 'good.example.com'
port = 5432
database = 'testdb'
query = ''


url = URL.create(
    drivername=drivername, username=user, password=password, host=host, port=port, database=database, query=query
)
# Show masked url
print(url)
# Show unmasked url (note escaped password)
print(url.render_as_string(hide_password=False))
```

Output

```
postgresql://alice:***@good.example.com:5432/testdb
postgresql://alice:password%40bad.example.com%3A5432%2Fsecretdb?@good.example.com:5432/testdb
```

`URL`s can also be created by passing a string to the [make_url](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.make_url) function. This function does not perform any URL-encoding, so it will not prevent such attacks.

---

* *Obligatory disclaimer: The security benefits of `URL.create` are a side-effect of it's functionality, it isn't a dedicated security tool. Other forms of attack may exist. If you are securing high-value information, hire security professionals.*